# Make Google Charts adapt the vertical axis to the data

Tags: google-visualization

I want Google chart to make better use of the vertical space available for this graph:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x150&cht=bvs&chxt=x%2Cy&chd=t:7,8,5,6
```

[image]

**QUESTION:** How to make the vertical axis adapt to the range of values automatically?
For instance, 0→max value would be great.

*Note: I could write a server-side algorithm to find the max value and use it as a parameter, but there is probably a better way to do this with Google Charts, right?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a server-side loop to check what is the maximum value, and then use it:

```
&chxr=1%2C0%2C" + max + "&chds=0," + max
```

Any better solution is welcome!